# how to save the data from iphone application to text file and save in documents

Tags: objective-c, xcode

As we know that it is possible to create pdf file in iphone application but i want that my data which is in table view must be saved in the documents of the application in a text file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a string to a text file using Xcode for iPhone dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129576/writing-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-xcode-for-iphone-dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a text file let it be "file.txt" and write required data, here "yourString" as follows,

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
 NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[stringWithoutSpaces writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

You can read saved data as follows,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
    NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```